Problem 7.5 from I.Martin Isaacs's Character Theory of Finite Group

Let $G$ be a finite group, $N \leq G$, and $\mathscr{S} \subset
\operatorname{Irr}(N)$.
Assume that induction to $G$ is an isometry on $\mathbb{Z} [\mathscr{S}]^\circ $ and $|\mathscr{S}| \geq 2$.
Suppose $\mathscr{S}_0 := \{ \xi \in \mathscr{S} \mid \xi \mathrm{\ is \ extendible \ to\ } G \}\ \neq \emptyset$.
Let $d:= g.c.d(\{ \xi(1) \mid \xi \in \mathscr{S}_0 \})$ and assume $d \mid \xi(1)$ for all $\xi \in \mathscr{S}$.
Show that $\mathscr{S}_0=\mathscr{S}$, $\mathscr{S}$ is coherent, and  that every $\xi \in \mathscr{S}$ has a unique extension to $G$.


My attempt:
(Imitating the proof of theorem 7.14)
Assume $\mathscr{S}_0 \subsetneq \mathscr{S}$.
Fix $\xi \in \mathscr{S} \setminus \mathscr{S}_0$.
Then $\xi(1)=ad$ and $d=\sum_{\chi \in \mathscr{S}_0} b_{\chi}\chi(1)$ for some integers $a, b_{\chi}$.
Put $\theta := \xi - a\sum_{\chi \in \mathscr{S}_0} b_{\chi}\chi\in \mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{S}]^\circ$.
For each $\chi \in \mathscr{S}_0$, fix an extension $\phi_{\chi} \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ of $\chi$.
Then $\theta^G =\Delta - a\sum_{\chi \in \mathscr{S}_0} b_{\chi}\phi_{\chi}$ and we can show that $\Delta \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ and that $\Delta(1)=\xi(1)$.
We see that $\Delta_N=(1+a\sum b_{\chi}[\chi^G, \Delta])\xi +\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a character of $N$ and $[\Gamma, \xi]=0$.

If we can show that $\Delta_N=\xi$, we have a contradiction.
This implies that $\mathscr{S}_0=\mathscr{S}$.

Assume that $\mathscr{S}_0=\mathscr{S}$.
We will show that $\mathscr{S}$ is coherent.
For each $\xi \in \mathscr{S}$, we fix an extension $\xi^*$ of $\xi$.
We extend $*$ on $\mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{S}]$ linearly.
It is easy to show that $*$ is an isometry and that $*$ extends the induction on $\mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{S}]^\circ$.

I have no idea how to prove that every $\xi \in \mathscr{S}$ has a unique extension to $G$.
